# $ENV:USERNAME returns the machine name when SCCM runs a script as admin with a non-admin logged in

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, administrator, non-admin

I have a script that needs to run from Software Center when a non-admin is logged in.

It needs to copy application data to `$ENV:USERNAME\AppData\<dir>\*` (among other things) and it needs to run as administrator to work properly.

The problem that I've discovered is that when the script is run on a non-admin profile with admin privileges the environment variable `$ENV:USERNAME` returns the machine name rather than the actual logged in username.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).Name` or you get the profile path from the registry :

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\APPDATA
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\LOCALAPPDATA
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\USERPROFILE
```

Choose your weapon :)

Comment: Awesome.  This worked like a charm.  I had to add ([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).Name.replace("$ENV:USERDOMAIN\","").  but this was perfect.

Comment: You are very welcome :-). You can click on the counter next to my answer to accept it, if you think it's appropriate

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do so.  I am sorry =(

Comment: There's a 15min timer iirc :-) ... but it's been an hour. Well, I don't know !